# Convert field to decimal Firebird

Tags: sql, casting, firebird

I am trying to convert a field to decimal. The field has 12.00000000 as a value but I need to have my results to 12.00, however, I have tried `select vendorID, Date, CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2), prices) from TableA` but it won't work with Firebird.

I need to convert this field to a decimal field. I know Firebird supports `CAST` but I am not able to proceed. Is there a way to tell the datatype of a field in Firebird?

```
select vendorID, Date, CAST(DECIMAL(10,2), prices) from TableA
```

Comment: InterBase and Firebird are not the same, they have diverged over the 18 years since Firebird was forked from InterBase 6. If you are using Firebird, then you are not using InterBase.

Answer (score 4):

You should [cast as described in Firebird documentation](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs.html#fblangref25-functions-scalarfuncs-cast): `CAST (expression AS datatype)`. Your query would then look like this

```
SELECT
  vendorID,
  date,
  CAST(prices AS DECIMAL(10,2))
FROM TableA
```

Comment: I have updated the link you used to point to the Firebird 2.5 language reference, as it is more complete than the Firebird 2.0 language reference update (which only documented changes since InterBase 6).